# JavaCC Syntax issue with understand ability

Tags: java, parsing, javacc, compiler-compiler

I am starting to learn Javacc and trying to figure out this problem but I can't seem to fully understand if I am doing this right or not.

So what I am doing is making a parser for a custom language and generating Java parser source code using Javacc.

I think I am doing this right but have a lot of doubt on if this is correct or not.

Here is the .jj file I have so far.

```
options {
  JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE = true;
  STATIC = false;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(Custom_Lexer)
  public class Custom_Lexer {}
PARSER_END(Custom_Lexer)


void Custom_Lexer_Program() :
{}
{
  <BEGIN> <CLPL>
  ( Custom_Lexer_Statement() )*
  <END>
  <EOF>
}

void Custom_Lexer_Statement():
{}
{
    STATEMENT()
    <SEMICOLON>
}

void STATEMENT():
{}
{
    LOOKAHEAD(2) OUTPUT_STATEMENT()     |
    LOOKAHEAD(2) INPUT_STATEMENT()      |
    LOOKAHEAD(2) VARIABLE_DECLARATION() | 
    LOOKAHEAD(2) VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT()  |
    LOOKAHEAD(2) IF_THEN_STATEMENT()
}

void OUTPUT_STATEMENT():
{}
{
    <OUTPUT> <EQUALS> EXPRESSION()
}

void INPUT_STATEMENT():
{}
{
    VARIABLE_DECLARATION()*
}

void VARIABLE_DECLARATION():
{}
{
    <VARIABLE> (<EQUALS> <INT> | <BOOL> | <STRING>)?
}

void VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT():
{}
{
    <VARIABLE> (<EQUALS> EXPRESSION()
}

void IF_THEN_STATEMENT():
{}
{
    <IF> EXPRESSION() <THEN> VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT() [<ELSE> VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT()]
}
//Will define these later after the above issues are fixed
void EXPRESSION():
{}
{
    LOOKAHEAD(5) BINARY_EXPRESSION()        |
    LOOKAHEAD(5) IDENTIFIER_EXPRESSION()    |
    LOOKAHEAD(5) LITERAL_VALUE_EXPRESSION() |
    LOOKAHEAD(5) PARENTHESIZED_EXPRESSION()
}


//Reserved words
TOKEN: { <CLPL:   "CLPL"   > }
TOKEN: { <BEGIN:   "BEGIN"   > }
TOKEN: { <END:     "END"     > }
TOKEN: { <OUTPUT:  "OUTPUT"  > }
TOKEN: { <INPUT:   "INPUT"   > }
TOKEN: { <IF:      "IF"      > }
TOKEN: { <THEN:    "THEN"    > }


TOKEN: { <INT:    "int"      > }
TOKEN: { <BOOL:   "bool"     > }
TOKEN: { <STRING: "string"   > }


TOKEN: { <SEMICOLON:     ";" > }
TOKEN: { <LEFT_PAREN:    "(" > }
TOKEN: { <RIGHT_PAREN:   ")" > }
TOKEN: { <PLUS:          "+" > }
TOKEN: { <MINUS:         "-" > }
TOKEN: { <MULTIPLY:      "*" > }
TOKEN: { <DIVIDE:        "/" > }
TOKEN: { <EQUALITY:     "==" > }
TOKEN: { <EQUALS:        "=" > }
TOKEN: { <GT:            ">" > }
TOKEN: { <LT:            "<" > }


TOKEN: { <BOOLEAN_LITERAL: "true" | "false" > }


TOKEN: { <INTEGER_LITERAL: (["0"-"9"])+ > }


TOKEN: { <STRING_LITERAL: "\"" (~["\"","\\","\n","\r"] | "\\" (["n","t","b","r","f","\\","\'","\""] | ["0"-"7"] (["0"-"7"])? | ["0"-"3"] ["0"-"7"] ["0"-"7"]))* "\""> }


TOKEN: { <IDENTIFIER: (["a"-"z"]|["A"-"Z"]|"_")+((["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","_"])*)? > }
```

Comment: There are unbalanced parentheses in the `VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT` production.  Something is missing or extra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unfinished, but looks like a reasonable start.  I'd suggest that you avoid all `LOOKAHEAD` specifications until you understand better what you are doing.  Try left factoring so that all choices can be made with the default lookahead method.

One problem I see is that the conflict between `VARIABLE_DECLARATION` and `INPUT_STATEMENT` can't be resolved since any `VARIABLE_DECLARATION` is also an `INPUT_STATEMENT`.